# c# converting object using DTOs

Tags: c#, dto

Good day,
I have these  classes I populate from db:

```
public class BaseProduct
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int MainCategoryId { get; set; }
        public MainCategory mainCategory { get; set; }
        public int MaterialId { get; set; }
        public Material material { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ProductVariant> productVariants { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ImageBase> ImageBases { get; set; }

        public int UnitsSold { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Discount { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
        public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    }

public class ImageBase
{
    [Key]
    [Column(TypeName = "bigint")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName ="varchar(max)")]
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName ="datetime")]
    public DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }

    public int BaseProductId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public BaseProduct baseProduct { get; set; }
    //TODO fix typo
    public string SaticPath { get; set; }
}
```

I want to convert them into these:

```
public class BaseProductCustomReturn
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public MainCategory mainCategory { get; set; }
    public Material material { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductVariant> productVariants { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BaseImageReturn> ImageBases { get; set; }

    public int UnitsSold { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
}

public class BaseImageReturn
{
    [Key]
    [Column(TypeName = "bigint")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }

    public int BaseProductId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public BaseProduct baseProduct { get; set; }
    //TODO fix typo
    public string StaticPath { get; set; }
}
```

The main difference is in BaseProductCustomReturn I have Ienumerable(BaseImageReturn)  instead of IEnumerable(ImageBase)

I wrote this dto conversion method

```
 public static IEnumerable<BaseProductCustomReturn> ConvertToDto(this IEnumerable<BaseProduct> baseProducts)
    {
        var baseProductCustomReturn = (from baseProduct in baseProducts
                                       select new BaseProductCustomReturn
                                       {
                                            Id = baseProduct.Id,
                                            Name = baseProduct.Name,
                                            Description = baseProduct.Description,
                                            mainCategory = baseProduct.mainCategory,
                                            material = baseProduct.material,
                                            productVariants= baseProduct.productVariants,
                                            ImageBases
                                       });
    }
```

As you can see I got stuck in converting ImageBase, how do I convert ImageBase to ImageBaseReturn? They ar both lists, so I cant convert One By One.

Comment: Roll your own loop or use LINQ (you are already using LINQ for your products, so just do the same for your images)

Comment: Do it in different dtoConvertion or it is possible to do it in the same ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use LINQ

```
ImageBases = baseProduct.ImageBases.Select(b => new BaseImageReturn(){/* Copy properties */}).ToList()
```

Note that most of the benefit from DTO-types comes from allowing you to have a more complex model without needing to take serialization concerns into consideration. For example allowing you to have private setters, and methods that does validation etc. In your example your DTO and model are nearly identical, so you will not gain a large benefit.

If you are using databases you might also consider using a Object Relational Mapper (ORM) like Entity Framework (EF).

Comment: I am already using entity framework to get info for BaseProduct, I just dont know how to convert it after I get data